# ASP.NET Core 2.1 on Visual Studio 15.7 Final

Tags: visual-studio, asp.net-core, visual-studio-2017

I've been working on my ASP.NET Core 2.1 project using the preview version of Visual Studio 15.7.x

Looks like VS 15.7 is now final. Can we now use that instead of preview versions of VS?

I've had a lot of issues with the preview versions and would love to switch to a stable version of VS.

Comment: You can download it here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/releasenotes/vs2017-relnotes#15.7

Comment: Thank you but that didn't answer my question :-)

Comment: Well! Probably yes, you are only changing to the final version of the IDE. It's probably already targeting 2.1 everywhere :)

Comment: Thanks again but I need a definitive answer. I appreciate your help though. I've had way too many issues with the preview versions and I'm just nervous at this point to do anything that could mess up my projects. Thanks again!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [Announcing .NET Core 2.1 RC 1](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2018/05/07/announcing-net-core-2-1-rc-1/) on .NET Blog:

> You can develop .NET Core 2.1 apps with Visual Studio 2017 15.7,
>   Visual Studio for Mac 7.5, or Visual Studio Code.

Comment: Awesome! I've been looking for the official word on this! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

The Visual Studio side of the equation is tooling. If Visual Studio 15.7 has the ASP.NET Core 2.1 tooling included in the release, then yes you can use it to develop ASP.NET Core 2.1 apps. However, if the ASP.NET Core 2.1 code is still in flux, that means the tooling could change as well, so until the framework release is final, it's still a better idea to continue using the preview build of Visual Studio.

It's worth noting that ASP.NET Core 2.1 is conspicuously missing from the release notes. It's very likely that that support was stripped from 15.7 to allow the release of other necessary features that were ready to ship. I haven't updated myself yet, so I can't say for sure, but your question may be moot.